# PopoverPresentationController not getting dismissed on touching outside

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I have a PopoverPresentationController which shows from the button like below.

[image]

[image]

I want to dismiss this popup on clicking outside popup. It should not dismiss on clicking inside popup. Below is my code.

```
_popup = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PopupViewController"];
_popup.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
_popup.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.button;
_popup.modalInPopover = TRUE;

[self presentViewController:_popup animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete this line:

```
_popup.modalInPopover = TRUE;
```

Comment: If I delete that line then popup dismisses on clicking inside it but no clicking outside.

Comment: Well I can’t reproduce that based on what you’ve told us. Something else is going on that you have concealed.

Comment: Well, I don't know the weirdness of Xcode. but after deleting this line and force cleaning project, it worked. Thanks